# destroying the joint

Tags: faces

See on the pic, The joint of two faces are **destroying the joint**, please help out to fix this. I tried **Shift+N**, but it doesn't work.



[image]

Comment: First thing would be to go to the "Overlays" panel and turn on "Face Orientation" and make sure all the faces are blue.

Comment: have you selected all the faces before the Shift N? Also, maybe you have inner faces...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots yeeah, after selecting all, it's working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Bad Normals]
So I made a simple cylinder with loop cut and flipped the normals on the top half. It looks very similar to your problem image. The image on the right shows the "Face Orientation" is red/blue instead of just blue like it should be.

Comment: How should we fix this?
We want plain faces joint...

Comment: Select all the red faces in edit mode, then Mesh -> Normals Flip.  Or select all faces, then Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate outside

Comment: It's also working... thanks @ron-jensen

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted as it fixed your problem.